# Are there any other software which has a function same as ListSurfacePlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I wanted to use `ListSurfacePlot3D`, but it is hard to apply the function to my large-size data set (3D point cloud more than 50000 points). The calculation time needed to render an image is too long, or the calculation cannot be accomplished because of an error, or the result shows jagged surface.

I think these problems are caused by inadequacies of both my PC and Math-kernel.

So, now I am looking for other software which can provide the same function as `ListSurfacePlot3D`.

I cheacked on Igor, Origin and MATLAB, but they cannot do not provide the functionality of `ListSurfacePlot3D`.

Could you give me some information?

Comment: That is not quite about Mathematica, is it? Maybe better try on SO or a more general site, once you add a description of `ListSurfacePlot3D` features?

Comment: Although I gave you an answer, I agree with Kuba that this question is out of scope and I voted to close it.

Comment: @kuba, halirutan Thank you for your advices. I check MeshLab, and also agree with that the topic is out of scope for this site.

Answer (score 2):

What you try to achieve can be done with [MeshLab](http://www.meshlab.net/). It's open source and as far as I can remember, it has several algorithms for that. Most notably, the Poisson Mesh Reconstruction.

[image]